# Trying to create websockets and using HttpSelfHostServer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, websocket

I just got handed a new project where most of the job was already done but I needed to change some things for my project. I have a self hosted server setup like this in a consoleapp:

```
        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

and a route configured like this:

```
        private static HttpSelfHostConfiguration CreateWebServerConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", Environment.MachineName, 80));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Api", "api/{controller}/{id}/{value}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional, value = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Defect", "defect/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Defect", action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Content", "content/{action}/{file}", new { controller = "Content"});
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{date}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional, date = RouteParameter.Optional });

        var templateConfig = new TemplateServiceConfiguration { Resolver = new DelegateTemplateResolver(name => ReadFileContent("Views", name))};

        Razor.SetTemplateService(new TemplateService(templateConfig));
        return config;
    }
```

This works perfectly, but I ran into a situation, where I didn't want the front end to pull with a timer on the server(currently auto refresh every 5 min). I want the server to update the frontend, when there is something new to update. I found the solution to this which would be websockets, but I have a lot of problems using those.

my .js file:

```
        (function() {
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
        } ws://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.replace('index.htm', 'ws.ashx') + '?name=' 
        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80/WebsocketServer.cs");

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            alert("message recv.");
            alert(event.data);
        };
        socket.onopen = function() {
            alert("open");
        }
        socket.onerror = function(errorEvent) {
            alert("Error");
            alert(errorEvent);
        };
        socket.onclose = function(closeEvent) {
            alert(closeEvent.code);
        }
    })();
```

I found multiple examples like this one: https://blog.simpleisbest.co.uk/2012/05/01/websockets-with-asp-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11/ but it doesn't seem to work for me, this is my files:

**WebsocketServer.cs**

```
    public class WebsocketServer : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new WebSocketManager());
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }

    }
}
```

**WebSocketManager.cs**

```
    public class WebSocketManager : WebSocketHandler
{
    public static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();
    public override void OnClose()
    {
        clients.Remove(this);
    }
    public override void OnError()
    {

    }
    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {

    }
    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        clients.Add(this);
        clients.Broadcast("Connected");
    }
}
```

The frontend returns closing code 1006 or CLOSE_ABNORMAL. My guess is the link to the backend isn't created?